# How to read a file (in a post request) in azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have posted a txt file through a Post request and i would like to read it and store in a string so that i can use cognitive services on the string. I tried converting the dynamic data variable to a string however when i log it, its blank, So is streamreader. Shouldnt stream reader have some text?

Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            Person p = new Person();

            string fname = req.Query["fname"];
            string lname = req.Query["lname"];
            

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            log.LogInformation("data to store is" + requestBody);
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            //fname = fname ?? data?.fname;
            //lname = lname ?? data?.lname;
           string text = Convert.ToString(data);
            log.LogInformation("data to store is"+text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
            {
                p.firstName = fname;
                p.lasttName = lname;
                p.text = text;

                //string filename = fname+".txt";
                Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                string filename = g + ".txt";
                await CreateBlob(filename, p, log, filename);

            }

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fname)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {fname} {lname}.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that your function is expecting a JSON body. Is that what you are passing in the POST API call? Can you edit the question with a screenshot of what your POST API call looks like (maybe via postman). Also where is the CreateBlob function?

Answer (score 1):

For reading ***File*** in post request you can use the `Http Request Form` to get the file details.

Use the `InputStream` to read the file. Check the below code for reference.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace functionreadfile
{
    public  static  class  Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  static  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var formdata = await req.ReadFormAsync();
            var filePath = "D:\\";
            string name = formdata["name"];
            var textfile = req.Form.Files["file"];
            if (textfile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var inputStream = new FileStream(filePath + textfile.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    // read file to stream
                        await textfile.CopyToAsync(inputStream);
                    // stream to byte array
                    byte[] array = new  byte[inputStream.Length];
                    inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    inputStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
                    // get file name
                    string fName = textfile.FileName;
                }
            }
            string requestBody = await  new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
            return  new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Same way you can use it in your code to read the file.